# New frame does not respect default font

Tags: fonts, ess, r

I use Emacs mostly to write R using [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/). I like a large font to reduce eye strain so the last line of my .emacs file is:

```
(set-default-font "Inconsolata-20")
```

If I open a file of R code, this appears as one would expect. However, additional frames opened with `C-x 5 2` have a tiny font. Typically this happens when I eval the buffer and want to look at the resulting ESS/R session in a separate frame.

I assume there is something overiding the default font, but cannot find what it might be. Strangely, sometimes the default font is respected, but I cannot reproduce.

How can I force all new frames to honor the default font?

[image: Tiny text in ESS window]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`set-default-font` by default sets the font for current frame only from the documentation <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`set-default-font`<kbd>RET</kbd> (emphasis mine)

> (set-default-font FONT &optional KEEP-SIZE FRAMES)
>
> This function is obsolete since 23.1; use `set-frame-font' instead.
>
> Set the default font to FONT. When called interactively, prompt for
>   the name of a font, and use that font on the selected frame.  When
>   called from Lisp, FONT should be a font name (a string), a font
>   object, font entity, or font spec.
>
> If KEEP-SIZE is nil, keep the number of frame lines and columns fixed.
>   If KEEP-SIZE is non-nil (or with a prefix argument), try to keep the
>   current frame size fixed (in pixels) by adjusting the number of lines
>   and columns.
>
> If FRAMES is nil, apply the font to the selected frame only. If FRAMES
>   is non-nil, it should be a list of frames to act upon, or t meaning
>   all existing graphical frames. Also, **if FRAMES is non-nil**, alter the
>   user's Customization settings as though the font-related attributes of
>   the `default' face had been "set in this session", so that **the font is
>   applied to future frames.**

So the solution is to do

```el
(set-default-font "Inconsolata-20" nil t)
```

Also please note that this function is obsolete since emacs 23.1. Use `set-frame-font` instead, the API is same

**Additional methods for setting font**

For sake of completeness I am mentioning additional methods for setting default font

Customizing `default-frame-alist`, mentioned by @Drew

```el
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Inconsolata-20"))
```

Customizing the `default` face, mentioned by @wasamasa, by doing something like the following

```el
(set-face-font 'default "Inconsolata-20")
```

Alternately you can use the `customize` interface, mentioned by @VitoshKa, <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face`<kbd>RET</kbd>`default`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: There is no need to do this change to Customize at every start. It's better to customize the `default` face instead to have the desired font family.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Can you expand on this please?

Comment: @SlowLearner, I guess @wasamasa meant `M-x customize-face RET default RET`

Comment: Or customize `default-frame-alist` to use the `font` parameter value you want.

Comment: @wasamasa I am not sure I understand why it is **better** to `customize` the `default` face. My understanding is that both methods are equivalent since `set-frame-default` internally customizes the `default` face. Anyways I have updated the answer to mention alternative ways to set the font

Comment: Using `set-frame-font` will instruct Emacs to add a customization to the theme-related settings in custom.el.  Either do this once interactively or manually by customizing the `default` face, but don't insert this call into your init.el as this will be done on every start then for no proper reason.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here, `set-frame-font` sets frame only for the current session, it does not alter the user's custom.el file. I guess you misunderstood the following line from the documentation `alter the user's Customization settings as though ... (font) had been "set in this session"`

Answer (score 0):

In customize-> saved options
expand the default font and uncheck the "inherit" option (which is set to nil)
This lets the 'new frame' inherit the default font.